# How to work-around limitations of iCloud Mail rules to emulate Mail.app rules?

Tags: icloud, mail.app, mail-rules

I have been using Mail.app to manage my personal and work email accounts forever, using many rules in the desktop Mail.app to manage the large volume of messages that pass through my accounts; however, as I've expanded to using an iPad and laptop alongside my desktop, I've started to run into issues with rules not being applied (e.g. if a message is viewed on a mobile device when the desktop or laptop is off).

I figured the solution was as simple as setting up the same rules directly on the server, via iCloud.com; however, I was disappointed to find that the range of actions for rules on iCloud is much more limited than those available on the desktop version of the app (e.g. there is no option whatsoever for copying a message to another folder).

**Has anyone come up with a work-around that would allow one to apply more sophisticated mail-sorting rules at the server level?** The one that I am most in need of is duplicating a message to a different folder (see below for additional context).

---

**Additional Context / Motivation**

With all the glitchiness of Mail.app rules in the past, I found the most effective method for my purposes was to have a message moved to the appropriate folder for organizing messages > create a duplicate, unread version marked with a green flag in my inbox (the flag would tell me that the rules had run successfully): this way, I see all the messages coming in (so nothing slips by by being sorted into a sub-folder without my noticing it come in), but can just delete the inbox copy, knowing that the message itself has been properly sorted.

Comment: Use a different mail provider and pay for it :( I use fastmail partially because of this.

Comment: @Mark curious to know why you settled on fastmail vs. something like google? I had an old, free Exchange account from my uni and started setting it up. It's better than iCloud server options, but not ideal, either. Appreciate your comment very much -- thanks for your time & help.

Comment: I have my own domain also fastmail allows good rules to move mail around